# Update command is not working in MySql work bench

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

"Table name = titanic"

This is my code:

```
UPDATE titanic SET Age = 100, Where Age = 0;
```

This is the error:

> 14:17:38   `UPDATE titanic Age = 1000, Where Age = 0`
> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= 1000, Where Age = 0' at line 1  0.000 sec

Comment: Remove a comma.

Comment: From the other side, the place of problem is at `=` posession... check does the space between `Age` and `=` is not non-breaking space, or some another space-like/nonprintable symbol is present.

Answer (score 1):

Try this syntax:

```
UPDATE titanic 
SET 
    Age = 100
WHERE
    Age = 0;
```

You have one ',' too many after the number 100.

This is how it should work.

Comment: Then you have a problem with a variable (case sensitive) or with the table. The syntax in my example is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the issue is with your syntax, **Please change**

```
UPDATE titanic SET Age = 100, Where Age = 0;
```

**To This**

```
UPDATE titanic SET Age = 100 WHERE Age = 0;
```

Try again and also make sure **Age** is in upper or lower case.

Comment: *sure Age is in upper or lower case* Non-quoted column names are case-insensitive in MySQL. Unless special setting enabled.

Comment: [Identifier Case Sensitivity](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html)